# The difference between a lemma and the Egorov's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

In my textbook, Egorov's theorem is proved with the help of a lemma. However, I have difficulty understanding the difference between the lemma and the theorem.

**The theorem is**

> [image]

**The lemma is**

> [image]

In the lemma, if we ignore $\eta$, isn't it "$\forall \epsilon$ there is a closed subset $F$ of $E$ and an integer $K$ such that $|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\epsilon$ for $x\in F$ and $k>K$"? Does not this already means $f_k$ converges uniformly on $F$ if the lemma holds? And look at $\eta$, since it can be arbitrary small, does not this already means the measure of $|E-F|$ can be arbitrary small?

The lemma indeed looks so similar to the theorem to me. I think I misunderstood something. Hope someone can help. Thank you!

The proofs of the lemma and theorem are attached below.

**The lemma's proof**

> [image]

**The theorem's proof**

> [image]

Comment: The set $F$ in the lemma depends on $\epsilon$ (and $\eta$ of course).